# strange pixels occur on a selected button which is over a UIVisualEffectView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uivisualeffectview

I have a view (UIVisualEffectView) with blur effect.

Above the view, I add some button with highlighted effects.

But when I press the button , strange things happen. I find some strange pixels [image: strange pixels on UIVisualEffectView]

How I can solve this problem , is this a bug of UIVisualEffectView?

Comment: check the image of selected and highlighted

Comment: There is no other pixels on image and selected image, I can assure that.

Comment: no no bro check image size on normal , selected and highlighted state

Comment: Get it ! Actually, I find it only happens on the simulator, but not on a real device , I think maybe is a small bug on the simulator or UIVisualEffectView. Thanks for your help, bro.

Comment: haa ha k bro have a nice day